# How to get data where certain rows of columns are null?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data, something like this:

```
|   | a | b                | d | e | f |
|---|---|------------------|---|---|---|
| 0 | a | {'d': 1, 'e': 2} | 1 | 2 |nan|
| 1 | b | {'d': 3, 'e': 4} | 3 | 4 |nan|
| 2 | c | NaN              |nan|nan|nan|
| 3 | d | {'f': 5}         |nan|nan| 5 |
```

I am trying to get all the values returned where column d,e,f have null values with this code but i am not getting any output.
`df[df[['d', 'e', 'f']].isnull().all(1)]`
I want output to be something like:

```
|   | a | b                | d | e | f |
|---|---|------------------|---|---|---|
| 2 | c | NaN              |nan|nan|nan|
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, need double `[]` and casting to `float`:

```
df[df[['d', 'e', 'f']].astype(float).isnull().all(1)]
```

Or:

```
df[df[['d', 'e', 'f']].astype('Int64').isnull().all(1)]
```

If `nan` are strings:

```
df[df[['d', 'e', 'f']].eq('nan').all(1)]
```

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo from my end.
I did try it but i am not getting the result.

Comment: I am using google colab, and my data has almost 60k records, running the code is taking more than 2 mins and eventually leading to crash the runtime.

Comment: @abhi - What is `print (df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: maybe some issue with colab notebook

Comment: @abhi - I guess data problem, so ask for thme.

Comment: Intializing it to the variable solved the issue, still donno why the issue was caused